# Is a ball that is not closed necessarily open?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I understand that we can have an interval that is neither closed or open, such as [0,1), but can a ball be neither closed or open? If so, what is an example of this?

Comment: How do you define the ball? Do you include points on the boundary? If the ball is of the form $\{x: d(a, x) < \delta \}$ for $\delta > 0$ then it will be open.

Comment: So if I'm trying to prove that a ball is open, is it sufficient to prove that it is not closed?

Comment: A ball can be both open and closed. For example, every subset of a discrete space is both open and closed.

Comment: A more specific example to what @ThePortakal wrote: " Now consider the space X which consists of the union of the two open intervals (0,1) and (2,3) of $\mathbb{R}$. The topology on X is inherited as the subspace topology from the ordinary topology on the real line $\mathbb{R}$. In $X$, the set (0,1) is clopen, as is the set (2,3)." - See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set

Comment: Basically, we define the "open ball" and "closed ball." I've never heard the term "ball" used without one of the two modifiers, or at least, without one of the two implied. You could think of a "general ball" as being a subset between the open and closed ball of the same radius. The set of values where a power series converges then would always be a "ball," but it wouldn't always be a closed or open ball. However, I don't see much use in that general concept of "ball."

Comment: I agree with @ThomasAndrews. The term "ball" came into use to generalize the notion of an interval to more general spaces. Just as an interval may contain varying amounts of its boundary, so too may a ball. But without a specific qualifier, or context in mind, the term alone is ambiguous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A ball is always either closed or open. In fact, there are only two types of balls.

- Open balls: sets of the form $\{y\in X: d(x,y)<r\}$.
- Closed balls: sets of the form $\{y \in X: d(x,y)\le r\}$.

Since, for a fixed $x$, $y \mapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous, it follows from the definitions that open balls are open and that closed balls are closed.

Comment: Great, thanks! I just wanted to make sure that if I show a ball is not closed, that is enough to prove it is open.

Comment: This is questionable in view of OP's comment. If $U$ is an open ball, and $K$ is the corresponding closed ball, then any set $B$ with $U\subset B\subset K$ could be considered a ball.